# Where was the kingsguard during the sack of King's Landing?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

The seven knights of the Kingsguard were stationed in different locations during the last days of King Aerys II. Gerold Hightower, Oswell Whent, and Arthur Dayne were stationed at the Tower of Joy, and later on killed there. Jaime Lannister was in King's Landing with Aerys. Barristan Selmy was at the battle on the Trident. I believe that Jon Darry was also on the Trident. I assume that Darry was killed during the battle, as I can only remember that Selmy surrendered. Is that correct?

Who was the last member of the Kingsguard, where was he at that time, and what happened to him? Was he with the king's wife on Dragonstone? As far as I know, beside slaying Aerys, Jaime only killed the pyromancer Rossart and not one of his Kingsguard brothers.

The reason I'm asking is that I am confused whether the King was only protected by one member of the Kingsguard.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Nymeros in our midst**
**[Prince Lewyn Martell](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Lewyn_Martell)** was the last member of the Kingsguard at that time<sup>[[1]](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Kingsguard#Aerys_II_Targaryen_.28262_AC-283_AC.29)</sup>. He was killed at the [Battle of the Trident](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Battle_of_the_Trident) by [Ser Lyn Corbray](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Lyn_Corbray); you'll note that Ser Lyn did this using his family's Valyrian Steel sword, [Lady Forlorn](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Lady_Forlorn).

Lewyn's death was a huge topic of anger for the Dornish along with [Princess Elia's](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Elia_Martell), as Lewyn was actually [Prince Oberyn](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Oberyn_Martell) and [Prince Doran's](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Doran_Martell) maternal uncle.

**As to your question**
[King Aerys II](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aerys_II_Targaryen) was in fact only protected by a single member of the Kingsguard, [Jaime Lannister](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jaime_Lannister) at that time. This is because the other members were off fighting the war for him. However, Aerys wasn't exactly defenceless; he had the [City Watch](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/City_Watch) (Gold Cloaks), part of his army and his [Wildfire cache](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Wildfire_plot) at [King's Landing](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/King's_Landing) and the [Red Keep](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Red_Keep) to protect him, as well as Jaime as his personal guard.

There have been many times where the Kingsguard go off to fight wars and command armies on behalf of the royal family. In this case though, there's speculation that [Rhaegar](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Rhaegar_Targaryen) had actually tried to supplant Aerys secretively, which is why the likes of [Oswell](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Oswell_Whent), [Gerold](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Gerold_Hightower) and [Arthur](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Arthur_Dayne) were at the [Tower of Joy](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Raid_on_the_Tower_of_Joy) instead of being more active during [Robert's Rebellion](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Robert's_Rebellion). However, the exact reasons are as yet unclear.

**Recap**
So, to recap, here is where all of Aerys' kingsguard were in [283AC](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/283_AC):

- Lord Commander **[Gerold Hightower](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Gerold_Hightower)**: At the Tower of Joy
- Ser [**Oswell Whent**](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Oswell_Whent): At the Tower of Joy
- Ser **[Arthur Dayne](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Arthur_Dayne)**: At the Tower of Joy
- Ser [**Jaime Lannister**](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jaime_Lannister): At the red Keep with Aerys
- Prince **[Lewyn Martell](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Lewyn_Martell)**: At the Trident
- Ser [**Barristan Selmy**](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Barristan_Selmy): At the Trident
- Ser [**Jonothor Darry**](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jonothor_Darry): At the Trident

Comment: Nice answer, would there be a reason why they only show 2 kingsguard at the ToJ in the tv series?

Comment: @Vahx seriously though, I assume it's because of budgeting / too many names to remember.

Comment: I believe we will see the final member of the Kingsguard inside the Tower of Joy

Comment: They actually name Ser Gerold Hightower in the show and state he was at the Tower. I believe Jaime notes it or sees it whilst looking through the White Book. I would speculate that it is more down to D&D being sloppy rather than Ser Gerold Hightower being inside the Tower but... we shall see.